# Existance of an invertible matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, field-theory

Show that there exists a $3\times 3$ invertible matrix $M\neq I_{3}$ with entries in the field $F_{2}$ such that
$M^{7} = I$.

Comment: Does the term "minimal polynomial" ring any bells?

Comment: How I construct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M^7=1$, then the minimal polynomial of $M$ divides $x^7-1$. Note that
$$ x^7-1=(x-1)(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1).$$
Over $\mathbb{F}_2$ we have $x-1=x+1$ and $(x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)=(x^3+x^2+1)(x^3+x+1),$ thus
$$ x^7-1=(x+1)(x^3+x^2+1)(x^3+x+1) \hspace{0.4cm} \text{over} \hspace{0.4cm} \mathbb{F}_2.$$
So, the minimal polynomial of $M$ must be $x^3+x^2+1$ or $x^3+x+1$.

For example, the companion matrix of $x^3+x^2+1$ is
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -1 \\
\end{bmatrix},$$
and the companion matrix of $x^3+x+1$ is
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix},$$
so this both matrices satisfy the requirements.

Comment: great. nice ans